# Android.Download Manager

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Вот код, в котором я загружаю файл в папку "Загрузки":

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(arrayList.get(posit).getUrl()));
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
            .setTitle("Download")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                        "filename.mp3");
enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

**Вот вопрос:**

Возможно ли таким образом загрузить файл к кэш?

Спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего надо указвать папку назначения так: `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, ":/storage/sdcard0/VKMusic/ghhh/filename.mp3");`

Comment: Это следует из названия параметра.

Comment: @vadrozh, дело в том, что мне нужно не в папку загрузки, а в любую (есть возможность выбора папки) или на карту памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Это должно помочь. **Для использования этого метода необходимо разрешение `write_external_storage` в манифесте**

```
public void file_download(String uRl) {
    // указываем директорию для загрузки
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dhaval_files");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs();
    }

    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            downloadUri);

    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
            .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/dhaval_files", "test.jpg");

    mgr.enqueue(request);
}
```

Оригинал [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16773944/6608568)